# Calculate running balance using two tables in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using two tables from where I am displaying this data one table name is `Purchcase_Table` and second is `Credit_Book`.

I want the following results:

```
ID      Date         Descripion    Total  Paid  Balance  Running Balance
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       28-Jan-17    Purchase      1000   6000  4000     4000
1       29-Jan-17    Purchase      5000   4000  1000     5000
1       30-Jan-17    P.Voucher     5000   2000  3000     3000
1       01-Feb-17    Purchase      9000   4000  5000     8000  
1       02-Feb-17    Purchase      1500   1000  500      8500
```

Please note that `P.Voucher` entry already calculates the total running balance when we issue credit payment voucher therefore in running balance we see "3000" as running balance you can see its total which is the total running balance of previous entry.

What I have tried so far is this but no luck

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Ledger]
    (@VenId Int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ledger TABLE (ID INT,
                           [DATE] DATETIME,
                           [DESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR(350),
                           TRANSACTION_TYPE NVARCHAR(50),
                           TOTAL DECIMAL(18,2),
                           PAID DECIMAL(18,2),
                           BALANCE DECIMAL(18,2),
                           RUNNING_BALANCE DECIMAL(18,2)
                          )

    INSERT INTO @Ledger
        SELECT 
            [Ven_Id], [Pur_Date], '(PURCHASE)', 'P', 
            [Grand_Total], [Paid], [Balance], 0 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Purchase_Table] pc
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Vendor] av ON av.ID = pc.Ven_Id
         /* P REFERS TO PURCHASE TRANSACTION AND CPV REFERS TO CREDIT PURCHASE VOUCHER */

        UNION

        SELECT 
            [VenId], [TransactionDate], '(VENDOR PAYMENT VOUCHER)', 'CPV', 
            [OriginalAmount], [PaidAmount], [RunningBalance], 0 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Credit_Book] vcb
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Vendor] av ON av.ID = vcb.VendorId

    SELECT 
        ID, [DATE], [DESCRIPTION],
        TOTAL_AMOUNT, PAID_AMOUNT,
        BALANCE_AMOUNT,

        CASE TRANSACTION_TYPE
           WHEN 'P' 
              THEN LAG([BALANCE_AMOUNT], 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) + [BALANCE_AMOUNT] 

           WHEN 'CPV' 
              THEN [BALANCE_AMOUNT]
        END AS RUNNING_BALANCE
    WHERE 
        ID = @VendorId 
    ORDER BY 
        [DATE]
END
```

The result I am getting is this

```
ID      Date         Descripion    Total  Paid  Balance  Running Balance
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       28-Jan-17    Purchase      1000   6000  4000     4000
1       29-Jan-17    Purchase      5000   4000  1000     5000
1       30-Jan-17    P.Voucher     5000   2000  3000     3000
1       01-Feb-17    Purchase      9000   4000  5000     8000  
1       02-Feb-17    Purchase      1500   1000  500      5500
```

You can see the last entry its adding last balance amount with current balance amount and showing false result. it should be 8500.

I know my question got too long and might be confusing too but just in case if anyone has a solution for this really appreciated.

Comment: share details about Purhcase_Table and second is Credit_Book. with sample data.

Comment: It will be too complicated to get into details of those tables. all i need to do is calculate running balance accurately just like i mentioned in my question. Do you have any solution for that so we can pick Last Running Balance value and add it with current Balance value?

Comment: I think you might have to go with a cursor.